# How to set a value to Time Picker dynamically in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, timepicker

I am using react time picker(rc-time-picker) in my code, I want to set the time picker value dynamically.

Here is my Time Picker Code

```
<span id="editstartTime">
     <span class="rc-time-picker timeStylstartTimeAdd">
        <input type="text" class="rc-time-picker-input" readonly="" value=""> 
             <span class="rc-time-picker-icon"></span>
     </span>
</span>
```

And I tried like this.

```
$('#editstartTime span input').val(this.state.shifts[index].startTime);
```

But it did not worked for me.

Please help me to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

[TimePicker](http://react-component.github.io/time-picker/#api) has a `value` state of type [`moment`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment), which holds the current value.

so e.g. if you instantiate with a state called `timePickerValue`:

```
<TimePicker value={this.state.timePickerValue} ... />
```

then you can modify `timePickerValue` using

```
this.setState({timePickerValue: newValue})
```

(In your example `newValue` would be `this.state.shifts[index].startTime`)

I suggest you try out [this example](https://github.com/react-component/time-picker/blob/master/examples/value-and-defaultValue.js) as it shows how to mutate the `TimePicker.value` state.

Answer (score 0):

```
 const now = moment().hour(0).minute(0);

 <TimePicker
                showSecond={false}
                value={moment().hours(13).minute(1)}
                className="time-picker"
                placeholder="HH:MM"
                onChange={(e) => {
                  console.log(e);
                  console.log(moment(taskCreateFormData.startTime));
                  onTimeChange(e, 'start');
                }}
                format={format}
                use12Hours
              />
```

if you take format for **use12Hours** then if you write **moment().hours(13).minute(1)** time like this then it will convert to **PM** time format